# More than one ng controllers in different <div>s in a single page

Tags: angularjs, ng-controller

Its day-2 I have started learning angularJS. I got to know

1. In an Application ng-app will be same for all or its a definition for the application.
2. A ng-app can have more than 1 ng-controller.
3. Based on controller name we can move the control to its implementation.
4. An application may have more than one div tag and every div may have different controller.

From above understaning I have written below sample code to test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body  ng-app="expressions" >

<div ng-controller="NGExpressionController">

<h1>This is AngularJS Expression example.......</h1>

<p>On String expression...</p>
Name: <input ng-model="name" type="text"></input></br>
Your name is {{name}}

</div>


<div ng-controller="NGExpressionControllerTwo">

<h1>This is AngularJS Expression example.......</h1>

<p>On String expression...</p>
Name: <input ng-model="adddress" type="text"></input></br>
Your name is {{address}}

</div>

<script>

    angular.module('expressions', []).controller('NGExpressionController',function($scope){
        $scope.name="Test Name";
    });


</script>

<script>

    angular.module('expressions', []).controller('NGExpressionControllerTwo',function($scope){
    $scope.address="Kolkata";   
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But above piece of code showing below error:

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=NGExpressionController&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined

Where I am going wrong? Is my understanding is wrong or code implementation is wrong.. Any form of help would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're implementing it twice (2 `<script>` tags) which means he won't recognise the first one anymore.

Working Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/eeFddCQSBg5Lm7SOyZH0?p=preview

```
<script>

angular.module('expressions', []).controller('NGExpressionController',function($scope){
    $scope.name="Test Name";
}).controller('NGExpressionControllerTwo',function($scope){
$scope.address="Kolkata";   
});
```

Using `<script>` to load `controllers` however is never a good practice, but since it's only your second day learning `Angular`, I'll leave it like that :) Anyway, you can always use https://www.codeschool.com/ You'll learn by doing.

Answer (score 0):

first your code has some errors , due incorrectly defining the module,

```
    <script>
     angular.module('expressions',[])
      .controller('NGExpressionController',function($scope){
          $scope.name="Test Name";
      })
      .controller('NGExpressionControllerTwo',function($scope){
          $scope.address="Kolkata";   
      });
   </script>
```

when creating an app you have to define a module once, and after defining a module you use that module by calling correctly module object,
for creating module use

```
   angular.module('yourModuleName',[])
```

to use that module again  use

```
 angular.module('yourModuleName')
```

no need of [ ], Square barckets, it used for defining dependencies for that module ,and when putting it wil result in re-initialising module again , and you will losse previously defined module properties,

**1** : ng-app directive will initialise an angular app, and it will be available for the whole app.  anyway we can manually create (bootstrap) multiple angular apps in a single application [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)

**2**  : An ng- app can have multiple Controllers , we can create our controllers and bind them whith any dom elements as we want .

```
   <div ng-controller="NGExpressionController">
   {{name}}
     <div ng-controller="NGExpressionControllerTwo">
     {{address}}
     </div>
   </div>
```

**3**  : based on the defined controller we can manipulate our logic or functions for the corresponding dom elements

**4**  : obviously yes , and you can nest your controllers to make use of $scope inheritance too. , be sure to use them wisely ...
happy coding...